# Rails - Is current_user friends with @user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm slowly implementing the ability to add and remove friends to a Rails app, but am having difficulty changing the "Add Friend" button to "Remove Friend" and vice-versa depending on whether or not the `current_user` is friends with the `@user` profile currently being viewed.

Here's what I have in my `user.rb` model so far (courtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105635/3273967) to another question):

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :passive_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"

has_many :active_friends, -> { where(friendships: { approved: true}) }, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend
has_many :passive_friends, -> { where(friendships: { approved: true}) }, :through => :passive_friendships, :source => :user
has_many :pending_friends, -> { where(friendships: { approved: false}) }, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend
has_many :requested_friendships, -> { where(friendships: { approved: false}) }, :through => :passive_friendships, :source => :user

def friends
    active_friends | passive_friends
end

def friend_with?(user)
    # ... How would I go about this?
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define `friend_with?` like so:

```
def friend_with?(other_user)
  friendships.find_by(friend_id: other_user.id)
end
```

You can then use `current_user.friend_with? some_user` to confirm whether or not the two users are friends.

Hope it helps!